# How can we set X-Frame-Options Response header in WebLogic and WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, weblogic, response, x-frame-options

I am new in web application, I'm facing issue of clickjacking in my web app which can be deployed on Oracle Weblogic and IBM WebSphere and not using any HHTP server.

To prevent from clickjacking I got to know about X-Frame-Options to set on response header.

I get some information from [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

how to set on HTTP server, but there were nothing specific to application server setting related to same.

I have following question -

1- Do we need a Web server to configure X-Frame-Options?

2- How to configure X-Frame-Options on Oracle Weblogic and IBM WebSphere

Answer (score 1):

You can set these response headers in any servlet, jsp, servlet filter, etc, with `HTTPServletResponse.setHeader()`.  Most HTTP proxy servers can manipluate response headers too, but it's not necessary.

WebSphere doesn't give you a configuration-only way to customize headers.

Comment: Thanks for answer @convener As you mentioned HTTPServletResponse.setHeader() is code changes, and we have a lot of pages we might uses iframe loading, so practically its not optimal solution for us to include this changes in code base. Instead we can do at server level, you can see in my question, I specifically asked any configuration  at application server level. Kindly help me with, Do we need web server for same, and is there any other way to configure on weblogic and websphere. Thanks